# “in the morning” vs. “in morning”

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-article, prepositional-phrases, time

1. I messaged you in **the** morning.
2. I messaged you in morning.

I am confused which sentence is correct. I think both are correct, but please help me out and tell me which sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: FYI, if you said (out loud) "I messaged you in morning", it would likely be misunderstood by a native speaker as "I messaged you in mourning", which means something very different.

Comment: What accent did the speaker use? A Yorkshire accent have have combined "in" and "the" into "int". As in "I message you int morning."

Comment: In American English, "message" is unlikely to be the verb you want.  You might say "I sent you a message" or "I emailed you" or "I texted you", depending on the context.

Comment: I've frequently heard "messaged" used in American English, albeit primarily within a 17-30 age range and only informally.

Answer (score 13):

Morning needs an article, so your example

> I messaged you in **the** morning.

But since this is past tense, it would be better to write:

> I messaged you **this** morning.

For the future it is OK though:

> I **will** message you in **the** morning.

Comment: Note that you'd only use *this morning* if it were the same day that you messaged the person. *in the morning* can be used in more situations.

Comment: Being past tense, if you had some other way to indicate the date, *in the morning* would be okay. For example "I never received the files due on October 18th. I messaged you in the morning as a reminder, but they still never arrived."

Answer (score 1):

user3169's answer is very good.

If you heard "in morning" as an expression (i.e. without the article) it's more likely to be in the context of "He/she is in mourning." This meaning is that the person is grieving over (typically) the death of a friend/relative. Clearly a very different meaning.