# In the evening or evening?

Tags: prepositions

I will send a mail **in the evening** or I will send a mail **evening**,
Which one is correct? Actually what i am saying is,
he can expect an email today  evening from me.

So for today evening, I can say **in the evening** or just **evening**?

Comment: This is a related question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39107/in-the-morning-vs-in-morning

Answer (score 3):

"In the evening" is correct.
To be slightly more casual, you could also say "this evening" or "tonight"